# Can you run multiple dry-runs concurrently during a TFS to VSTS migration?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-migration

Currently, one of our migrations has stalled on step one. I need do some testing and was thinking about kicking off another. A previously deleted migration took less than half the time of where I am now.

In case anyone was wondering how long these migrations take:

Previous Migration (17GB) took around 13 hours.
Now I'm at 20GB and on hour 24...

Thanks,

Comment: Regarding the time,it's depend on actual size of collection database, did you validate the collection before migration?

Comment: Someone from Microsoft got back to me on the long step time. Turns out the DACPAC expansion is going extremely slow, may be due to throttling on the blob container. We are setting up some throttle monitoring. We did validate the migration and the size tests did not show any warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run multiple dry-runs concurrently, but should be for different collections, also I believe the number of import requests that can come from a tenant in a day is capped to 5.

Regarding the migration time, it's depended on the actual size of collection database.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Someone from Microsoft got back to me on the long step time. Turns out the DACPAC expansion is going extremely slow, may be due to throttling. We are setting up some throttle monitoring.